# What minimum options should be given to configure for installing dbus across machines on shared directory?

Tags: d-bus

I am installing dbus from source on Redhat 6 server on NFS share to be used across all the servers (which are mostly similar).

Along with `--prefix`, which other options are required?

The reason for this is: some gtk related packages require dbus version above 1.8.0 and the current version is less than this. We don't want to effect the running processes in all servers and want to install separate dbus in a shared path.

After installing, do i need to just simply run the binary, that's all? I am hoping it won't conflict with existing dbus binary and the processes that depend on that dbus.

I am following the instructions in linuxfromscratch. But for shared installation, there is no specific instructions: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.7/general/dbus.html

**EDIT 1:**

***Some thoughts:***

- `--with-system-socket=/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket_1.8.0` (to avoid conflict with existing dbus socket)
- `--with-session-socket-dir=` (I am guessing it will create random sockets in tmp, so I guess it's not required)
- `--with-dbus-daemondir=/NFS_share/bin`
- `--with-system-pid-file=/var/run/messagebus_1.8.pid`

Then after installing, I need to create this `/var/run/dbus_1.8.0` in all servers and start the dbus agent from `/NFS_share/bin`. Am I right?

**EDIT 2:**

Along with the above options, I am adding the following options too: `--disable-static --disable-systemd --without-systemdsystemunitdir`.

And not sure if I need to add the following option to: `--with-console-auth-dir` and if, what it is exactly?

Comment: I have no idea about the required build flags, I just want to tell you that running multiple instances of dbus is no problem at all. You just have to make sure, that every application chooses the correct(TM) instance using the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS environmentvariable. Another hint, dbus can use an existing X11 session to share its address information. You should disable that for your second dbus to minimise the risk of interfering.

Comment: @Bananguin How to disable that option of using X11 session?